# Where I must put my jsp files in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot

I am writting to you because I don't know where I must put my JSP files in a SpringBoot application..

[A screen of my application's files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b757T.png)

Thank you in advance for your response,
Noman.

PS: Sorry I can't say Hello at the beginning of my post, it is always deleted..

Comment: Thank you I am going to read this post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your files to `src/main/resources/static` (or `src/main/resources/public` or `src/main/resources/resources`). All those are registered by Spring Boot autoconfig.

Also you should add following property to `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much!! But I don't have a static file.. I have to create one ?

Comment: Of course, you should create it

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

its esey to add jsp files in spring 
the following steps is important for that:
- create folder in src/main called webapp
- create inside it folder called WEB-INF
- add this lines to your pom file

```
    <!-- Spring MVC framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

- create the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
- create the web.xml file

you can visit the URl for more details about the steps [press here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/)